# how to make a div appear first in html code in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, optimization, seo, search-engine

Okay, so this is just an SEO based question.

I have content that needs to be served up to search engines first so in the html code, I want it to be parsed first before other content. But then under it, I have content that I want served to the users first.

Here is my code simplified (jquery library is called first before, style tags and script tags off):

HTML:

```
<div id="hidden-content">
    <div class="seo-priority">
        This div has content that I need to serve up to search engines first 
        but I want users to see it last
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="usr-priority">
        This contains the content that needs to be shown to the user first
    </div>
<div id="shown-content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.seo-priority {
    padding:50px; margin:10px; background-color:rgba(234,23,122,.7);
}
.usr-priority {
    padding:50px; margin:10px; background-color:rgba(23,32,122,.5);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#hidden-content').contents().appendTo('#shown-content');
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hilkiah/9fzbpqz2/7/

Question is two-part: first, since I use jquery, if the user disable javascript, it will not work as planned. Is there any work-around to this? Secondly, does anyone have any experience with this and what did you guys do it?

Please be aware that I am using bootstrap so I want the site to be responsive and so I don't like the fixed positioning with css. Unless there is a way to o that with css.

Also: YES, I have researched stack-overflow for similar questions but they are not fully informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Based on your clarification in the comments, here is a CSS solution

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="seo-priority">This div has content that I need to serve up to search engines first but I want users to see it last</div>
    <div class="usr-priority">This contains the content that needs to be shown to the user first</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.seo-priority {
    padding:50px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:rgba(234, 23, 122, .7);
    display: table-footer-group; 
}
.usr-priority {
    padding:50px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:rgba(23, 32, 122, .5);
    display: table-header-group;    
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9fzbpqz2/10/

*This will not work in IE8 or lower versions*

Comment: ok Sam, thanks for the first response. But I'm kinda confused still. The idea is to have seo content appear above user other content in the html code but only to visually render on the browser in the opposite manner: user content above seo content. This has to be the case even with javascript turned off. In other words NOo hidding of content at any time. Am I making sense?

Comment: Well, Sam, thanks. The display: table-*-group. Who would've thought? Well, you I guess. This solved my problem. Thanks kindly!